# Warning on escaped characters when reading paths

Tags: matlab, path, escaping

This is the path for the images dataset given to a structure variable `VCopts.imgepath`

```
VCopts = 

  struct with fields:

       dst: 'HollywoodHeads'
        dr: 'C:\Users\Harsh\Downloads\Compressed\cnn_head_detection\data'
   imgepath: 'C:\Users\Harsh\Downloads\Compressed\cnn_head_detection\data\HollywoodHeads\   JPEGImages\%s.jpeg'
```

So `VCopts.imgepath` has this content:

```
     VCopts.imgepath = 'C:\Users\Harsh\Downloads\Compressed\cnn_head_detection\data\HollywoodHeads\   JPEGImages\%s.jpeg'
```

If I now try to use [`sprintf`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), it should return a string variable. It was working fine in Linux but in Windows it throws an error:

```
  sprintf(VCopts.imgepath,'test')
  Warning: Escaped character '\U' is not valid. See 'doc sprintf' for supported special characters. 

  ans =

        'C:'
```

How can I use `sprintf` to generate a valid variable on Windows, as I did on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run into the problem that the backslash means "escape the next character in this string", but that Windows also uses it as folder separator. You need to tell MATLAB to escape the escaping function of the backslash by doubling it, or replace it by UNIX's folder separator `/`, the forward slash.

This can easily be done with [`strrep()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html)

```matlab
new_path = strrep(old_path,'\', '/');
```